# TCPDF - large files vs memory exhausted

Tags: php, pdf-generation, tcpdf

i want to ask, if anyone has been dealing with generating files w thousands of small pages (about to generate serial number stickers). In finale i may be creating document with **7-15k small pages** containing only QR code using builting function + short text + bookmark, so far sometimes i get memory exhausted with setting 512MB limit. Resulting file is not so big, about 10-30 MB (depends on used settings, on current state I have filesize about **1MB per 350 pages**)

With above in mind, "Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted" (512MB) feels to be the issue of Tcpdf not clearing memory objects maybe, so want to ask, did anyone handle similar situatiuon? I see two options:

1. Generate smaller files (say batch per 1000 pages), save them on server filesystem, and then either merge them, or make a zip file for download.
2. Cache the generated parts in-memory and just merge them on the fly without saving to server disk.

Is the option 2 actually possible? Can i cache pages to merge them later? Its my prefered choice, but not sure it si possible. Did anyone do it? Or some TCPDF command to free up objects? Or other ideas to handle the memory issue? Option 1 is the obvious reason, but id like to not use filesystem during generation, if there is a way.